# How to avoid large switch statements and/or regular expressions when converting code from one language to another

Tags: c#, regex

I have to convert a few hundred test cases written in Java to code in C#. At the moment all I could think of is define a set of regular expressions, try to match it on a line and do an action based on which regex matched.

Any better ideas (this still stinks).

An example of from and to:

Java:

```java
Request request = new Request(testRunner)
request.setUsername("userName")
request.setPassword("password")
log.info(request.getRequest())
```

C#

```cs
var request = new LoginRequest(LoginParams);
request.Username = "userName";
request.Password = "password";
var LoginResponse = Account.ExecuteCall(request, pathToApi);
```

Comment: "How to avoid large switch statements..." - Take this time to actually figure out what the code does and refactor it. The new language may have a better way. Signed, the guy currently converting to a python project

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an automatic conversion tool, there are some out there but they aren't 100%. I'd avoid writing one yourself though...

Comment: When I needed the same I avoided language specific features (for example properties in C# ,the var keyword).For example your initial java code is valid C# code if you add the functions setUsername /setPassword /getRequest to your Request class

Comment: @GeorgeVovos - I respectfully disagree, adding the methods would still need you to add a backing field which is (possibly) more easily covered with an auto-property. I don't want to start a war over why Java/C# use certain methods/syntax and which is better, but you should fully embrace your new surroundings

Comment: You can *"convert"* your jar to a .NET assembly using IKVM. You'll still be getting the Java API but at least you won't have to change a lot of source code.

Answer (score 1):

The source I'm trying to convert is from SoapUI and the bits of script involved are within TestSteps of a humongous XML file. Also, most of them are simply forming some sort of request and checking for a specific response so there shouldn't be too many types to implement.

What I ended up doing was defined a base class (Map) that has a Pattern property, a Success indicator and the lines of Code that it results to after a successful match. In some cases a certain line can be simply replaced by another one but in other cases (setUserName) I need to extract content from the original script to put in the c# code. In other cases, a single line might be replaced with more than one. The transformation is all defined in the Match function.

```cs
public class SetUserName : Map
    {
        internal override string Pattern { get { return @"request.setUsername\(""(.*)""\)"; } }

        public override void Match(string line)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(line, Pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Success = true;
                CodeLines = new Code<CodeLine>
                {new CodeLine("request.Username = \"" + match.Groups[1].Value + "\"")};
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I put the maps in a list ordered by occurrence and loop through each line of script:

```cs
foreach (string scriptLine in scriptLines)
            {
                string line = Strip(scriptLine);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || Regex.Match(line, @"^\s+$").Success)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Map[] RegExes =
                {
                    new Request(), 
                    new SetUserName(), 
                    new SetPassword(), 
                    new RunRequest()
                };

                foreach (Map map in RegExes)
                {
                    map.Match(line);
                    if (map.Success)
                    {
                        codeList.AddRange(map.CodeLines);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```